# Did C.S Peirce ever express anything close to the paradigm shift concept?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science

Since the study of Peirce seems to have a large number of papers in the philosophical corpus where researchers ascribe to him several concepts that were (re?)discovered several decades after his death I was wondering if he prefigured anything in the same vein to the concept of paradigm shift.

Comment: [McDonagh](https://www.jstor.org/stable/284785) connects some of Peirce's ideas on fixation of belief to Kuhnian paradigm shifts:"*As early as 1877, C. S. Peirce characterized a 'particular habit of mind' as a 'guiding principle of inference' that identifies those facts having 'interest as objects of research', a function also characteristic of a paradigm.*" But it is a faint connection. Peirce believed in unique "right" theory "at the end of inquiry", so the shifts are just corrections to temporary erroneously fixed habits. A mild form that even anti-Kuhnian realists do not dispute.